# Order of components in a JPanel (Java)

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

How can I decide the order of components when using a JPanel? My code looks something like this:

```
panel = new JPanel();

panel.add(a);
panel.add(b);
panel.add(c);
```

[...]

```
panel.remove(b);
```

[...]

```
panel.add(b);
```

Now, b is added at the end (right). How can I add b again in the middle?

Comment: Use a layout and read documentation about the particular layout manager.

Comment: dont use flowLayout. Use Grid or GridbagLayout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a component at index:

> panel.add(b, [index]);

Note that the index is 0-based.

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
add(Component comp, int index)
```

to insert a component at a given index.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you know the index where you want to put your component, you can use

[`add(b, index)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#add%28java.awt.Component,%20int%29)

Answer (score 0):

Use index. Also, you may like to look at MigLayout, a library. The best layout manager IMO, very easy to use.